# Mean number of edges per node in a hypercube graph in which random node are deleted

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, graph-theory

I have the following problem. Suppose we have a hypercube of dimension $L$. Then the number of nodes is given by $n=2^L$ and the number of edges is given by $e=L*2^{L-1}$. Now each node is deleted with a probability given by $(1−p)$. **The question is, what is the average number of edges per node $\bar{d}(L,p)$ of the resulting graph for given $L$ and $p$.** 
I know that the mean number of edges is given by $\bar{e}=p^2*L*2^{L-1}$ and the mean number of nodes is given by $\bar{n}=p*2^L$. 
The number of edges per node is given by $d=2*e/n$. But since $\bar{e}$ and $\bar{n}$ are depentend variables $\bar{d}=2*\bar{e}/\bar{n}=p*L$ is wrong.

**Edit 1**: I was able to calculate $\bar{d}(L,n)$ that is the mean number of edges per node for a random hypercube with dimension $L$ and a given number $n$ of "survived" nodes. Maybe this helps?
$$\bar{d}(L,n)=\frac{(n-1)*L}{2^L-1}$$
With $\bar{d}=2*\bar{e}/n$ in this case this also leads to
$$\bar{e}=\frac{L*n(n-1)}{2*(2^L-1)}$$

**Edit 2**: With the following equation given by gt6989b I get:
$$\bar{d}(L,p)=\sum_{v=0}^{2^L}\overline{n}(L,v) \Pr (v; p, 2^L)=\sum_{v=0}^{2^L}\frac{(v-1)L}{2^L-1} \binom{2^L}{v}p^v(1-p)^{2^L-v}=\frac{(2^L p-1)L}{2^L-1}$$
So I get from $\bar{d}(L,n)$ to $\bar{d}(L,p)$ by replacing $n$ with $p*2^L$ which somehow makes sense. So far everything sounds right, but I noticed that
$$\bar{d}(L,p)=\frac{(2^L p-1)L}{2^L-1}$$
becomes negative for sufficiently small values of $p$. I am now wondering if something is still wrong.

Comment: You have to see the argument for computing $\bar{e}$ and see if you can adapt it to $\bar{d} = \bar{e}/\bar{n}$...

Comment: The formula $\bar{d}(L,n)=\frac{(n-1)*L}{2^L-1}$ becomes negative when $n=0$, which is what's causing your negative values. You have to decide: what do you want $\bar{d}(L,0)$ to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you computed $d(L,n)$ correctly, you have
$$
\mathbb{E}[d(L)] = \sum_{k=0}^{2^L} d(L,k) \mathbb{P}[n=k]
$$
where the probability in question is easy since $n \sim\mathcal{B}(2^L,p)$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you are doing there. What is $\mathbb{P}[n=k]$ and $\mathcal{B}(2^L,p)$. What I am looking for is $\bar{d}(L,p)$

Comment: @HighwayJohn $n$ is binomially distributed with parameters $2^L$ and $p$, and what I called $\mathbb{E}[d(L)]$ is what you are calling $\bar{d}(L,p)$.

Comment: Using your equation and performing the sum this would lead to $\bar{d}(L,p)=L*(2^L*p-1)/(2^L-1)$. This would be the same as using $\bar{d}(L,n)=L*(n-1)/(2^L-1)$ and to replace $n=2^L*p$.

Comment: I am just a bit puzzeled by the fact, that this would be the same.

Comment: Moreover I am confused by the fact that $\bar{d}(L,p)$ becomes negative then for sufficiently small values of $p$.

Comment: Otherwise the results suits to the numerics, so the results seems to be correct.

Comment: @HighwayJohn $\bar{d}$ is never negative since $d(L,k) > 0$ and $\mathbb{P}[\cdot] \ge 0$ as well

Comment: $d(L,0)$ is actually negative. I guess I would have to define that differently

Comment: Or I perform the sum differently by starting with $k=1$. Then it also works...

Comment: @HighwayJohn if $p=0$ you are taking out all of the vertices almost surely :) so your limit is $0/0$